# How to handle upside down question mark in ssis

Tags: ssis

I am trying to import table from Oracle db to sql server 2008 through SSIS. I am getting upside down special character in one columns. Please let me know if we could handle with variable or data conversion tool.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Within the derived column transformation you can utilize the Replace Function in an expression to remove this character with a "" (0 value blank). You may need to use a text editor like notepad ++ with the "Show All Characters" option turned on to see the offending character so that you can place this in your SSIS expression.